# Как проверить, есть ли остаток от деления чисел в С++?

Tags: c++, математика

Как получить остаток от операции целочисленного деления?

Answer (score 12):

очень просто

```
if (x % t != 0) {
    cout << "при делении x на t есть остаток" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "остатка нет" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

С [математической точки зрения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC), операция вычисления остатка в C/С++ для отрицательных чисел, например `-11 % 8 == -3`, выдаёт не тот результат к которому мы привыкли со школьной скамьи. Конечно, это [вопрос договорённости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/229503/214732), но...
Эта проблема иногда [вызывает недоумение](http://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/4401720.all) и [горячие споры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229375).

Если задача определить лишь отсутствие остатка, тогда достаточно `%`. Однако, есть частное решение когда делитель - это число степени 2. Этот же способ является наиболее простым для определения остатка от деления на числа больше 1 равные степени 2.

```
int a;
int b; //2 в степени n
if (a & (b - 1))
    //остаток от деления присутствует. Например, -11 & (8 - 1) == 5
else
    //остаток равен нулю. Например, -8 & (8 - 1) == 0
```

Почему это важно? Рассмотрим последовательность `mod(n, 4)`

Для n&(4-1) последовательность периодическая

```
  n     -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8    
n&3  3            *           *           *           *     
     2         *           *           *           *        
     1      *           *           *           *            
     0   *           *           *           *           *
```

Для n%4 последовательность, вообще говоря, непериодическая

```
  n     -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8    
n%4  3                                    *           *     
     2                                 *           *        
     1                              *           *            
     0   *           *           *           *           *  
    -1            *           *                             
    -2         *           *                                
    -3      *           *
```

Работать с периодической последовательностью гораздо приятней там где требуется соблюдать равные интервалы между событиями. Можно соорудить конструкцию типа

```
switch (i & 3) {
case 0: /*событие 1*/; break;
case 1: /*событие 2*/; break;
case 2: /*событие 3*/; break;
case 3: /*событие 4*/; break;
}
```

и быть уверенным, что каждое событие будет возникать с завидной регулярностью независимо от знака `i` и дополнительных `case` не потребуется.

Comment: Простите, почему вы решили, что вопрос про отрицательные числа?

Comment: @Kromster, вероятно сыграло роль число голосов вопроса :)

Comment: @Kromster, А почему собственно и нет. В вопросе диапазон не уточняется, а KoVadim привёл версию, которая может быть не оптимальна в некоторых случаях. Опять же, в моём ответе приводится  альтернативное решение и объясняется почему, разве это плохо?