# Как получается остаток 2?

Tags: деление

Как при делении -3 на 5 получается остаток 2(3%5=2) ?

Comment: может я не понял вопроса,но получается "-0.6"

Comment: Эта неделя прямо какая-то *особая*

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: Как-то так: -3 = 5*(-1) + 2, где 2 - остаток

В остальном читайте про деление с остатком хотя в той же википедии, ссылку на которую дал ниже @Etki.

Comment: Повтор вопроса http://hashcode.ru/questions/229375/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

данный вопрос [уже поднимался тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229375/php-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD) (даже гуру Хэшкода)

Я остаюсь при своем мнении:

> -15 / 2 = -7 (-1)

Обратное действие:

> -7 * 2 + (-1) = -15

Немного в расписанном варианте

> -15/2 = -(15/2) == -(7 + 1/2) == -7 - 1/2 == -7(-1).

Comment: gcc (и инженеры Intel, посредством x86) согласны с Вами (а кто спорит?)

Answer (score 0):

Система стремится к равновесию.Равновесие это ничто,это обозначают 0. Деление это функция, которая считает сколько раз мы можем забрать одно из другого. -3 это три частицы анти материи.Сколько раз мы из трех частиц(не важно каких, материя или анти материя)мы можем забрать 5 частиц?Нисколько, мы не можем этого сделать.Ну у нам не получилось это сделать а что на руках теперь имеем?По факту мы имеем 3 частицы анти материи и 2 частицы материи. Когда создавали инструмент "математика" создали два инструмента, в одном,в процессе уничтожают 3 частицы анти материи(-3),в другом 2 частицы материи(2).