# Как округлить число в большую сторону

Tags: c#, математика, округление

Есть выражение

```
1/30
```

Как округлить результат до целого числа? Например чтобы получилось число `1`

Answer (score 11):

Например,

```
Math.Ceiling(1.0/30.0)
```

Не забывайте, что вы используете целочисленное деление. Результат деления 1/30 — уже 0. Поэтому перейдите к делению дробных чисел (1.0/30.0 = 0.03333333...), а уж это число округляйте вверх.

Answer (score 7):

Используйте [Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.ceiling(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Math.Ceiling(1.0/30.0)
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно без Math: `(a + b - 1) / b`

Comment: Это для случая _положительного_ `b`.

Comment: да, можно тогда модуль b прибавить

Comment: Вроде получается неправильный ответ при этом: http://ideone.com/cpaPC3

Comment: Мда... Ну костыль тогда прикрутить разве что - Все по модулю брать, умножать на знак а и на знак b.

Comment: Вообще, направление округления при отрицательном знаменателе — это [какая-то боль](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229375/10105).

Answer (score 5):

<s>Вариант с целочисленным делением выглядит так:
`(a*b+b*b-1)/(b*b)`</s>

Найдём вариант с целочисленным делением.
Нетрудно проверить, что `ceil(a/b) = - floor(-a/b)`.
Т.е. если `a/b` - это округление вниз, то `-(-a/b)` это округление вверх.

Если при целочисленном делении дробная часть просто отбрасывается (что соответствует операции trunc), то в случае `ab>0` округление вверх - это `-(-a/b)`,
 а в случае `ab<0` - это `a/b`.

Comment: `-4 / 2` по вашей формуле даёт `-1`, а надо `-2`: http://ideone.com/PXJ1xn

Comment: @VladD Исправлено

Comment: Хотел поставить +1, но не могу: уже стоит.

Answer (score -2):

С точки зрения постановки задачи, то да, вариант

```
Math.Ceiling(1.0/30.0);
```

будет верным.

Но вот с точки зрения логики лучше бы все-таки использовать

```
(int)Math.Round(1.0/30.0, 0);
```

Округление происходит в ближайшую сторону

Comment: Может хоть комментарии будите оставлять за что минусы? а то как бы ответ то верный

Comment: Заголовок вопроса "Как округлить число в большую сторону", а ты советуешь Round. Вот и минусят :)