# Формула числового ряда 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50

Tags: алгоритм, математика, любой-язык

Есть бесконечная последовательность "красивых чисел":

```
... 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, ...
```

Как для произвольного числа `x`, `1e-10 < x < 1e+10` найти следующее за ним "красивое" число?

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+5%2C+10%2C+20%2C+50&language=russian&go=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA

Answer (score 5):

Простая идея такая. Пусть данное число `x`.

1. Находим десятичный логарифм числа. Округляем его вниз (`floor`) до целого, пусть результат будет `n`.
2. Вычисляем 10 в степени `n` (умножением или через экспоненту), получаем `N`. Число `N` является степенью десятки, причём `N` ⩽ `x` < `10N`.
3. Это значит, что искомое число — одно из `N`, `2N` и `5N`. Сравниваем `x` с `N`, `2N` и `5N`, находим результат.

---

4. В принципе, из-за проблем с точностью вычислений с плавающей запятой мы могли получить в шаге 2 неправильный `N`. Поэтому, возможно, имеет смысл добавить в шаг 2 ещё две проверки:

   - если `x` оказалось меньше `N`, уменьшить `n` на единицу и повторить шаг 2 (или просто разделить `N` на 10 и перепроверить)
   - если `x` оказалось больше или равно `10N`, увеличить `n` на единицу и повторить шаг 2 (или просто умножить `N` на 10 и перепроверить).

Answer (score 2):

#### Python, itertools

**Наивная реализация:** делаем последовательность `[..., 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, ...]`.

Берем `range(-10, 10)` и отображаем его в `[..., 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, ...]`
Перемножаем множества `[1, 2, 5]` и `[... 0.1, 1, 10, ...]` - получаем `[..., (1, 0.1), (2, 0.1), (5, 0.1), (1, 1), (2, 1), ...]`.
Перемножаем элементы каждого кортежа - из `(5, 0.1)` получается `0.5`.
Находим первый элемент, которые больше `x`:

```
from itertools import *
from operator import *
from math import *
def next_pretty_number(x):
    exp10 = lambda x: pow(10, x)
    powers_of_10 = map(exp10, range(-10, 10)) # ...0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, ...
    seq = starmap(mul, product([1, 2, 5], powers_of_10))
    return next(dropwhile(lambda y: y < x, seq))
```

**Правильная реализация:**
Вся последовательность от 1e-10 до 1e+10 нам не нужна. Достаточно взять десятичный порядок `x` и умножить на него `[1, 2, 5, 10]`:

```
def next_pretty_number(x):
    scale = 10**floor(log10(x))
    seq = [scale*1, scale*2, scale*5, scale*10]
    return next(dropwhile(lambda y: y < x, seq))
```

#### C++

Алгоритм на Python можно переписать на С++, сохранив такую же выразительность:

```
auto scale = pow(10, floor(log10(x)));
double seq[] = {scale*1, scale*2, scale*5, scale*10};
auto next_pretty_number = *std::lower_bound(seq, seq+4, x);
```

Comment: Работает.Мой вариант для чуть измененного ряда на rust. 
// Ряд 1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000 ...
fn next_pretty_number(x: f64) -> i32{
        let scale = 10f64.powf(f64::floor(units_in_tick.log10()));
        [1., 2.5, 5., 10.].into_iter()
            .map(|item| f64::floor(item * scale))
            .find(|item| item >= &units_in_tick)
            .unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("unresolved")) as i32
    }

Answer (score 2):

#### C, по мотивам [oeis.org/A051109](https://oeis.org/A051109)

Берем элементы из списка `[1,2,5]` так что индекс элемента - остаток от деления некоторого числа `n` на длину списка, и домножаем их на `pow(10, n/3)`.

Так как `n` может быть отрицательно, надо добавлять смещение чтобы операции `%` и `/` производились над положительными числами ([подробнее тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229375/177684)).

В С и С++ вместо списка целых чисел можно взять строковый литерал.

```
double next_pretty_number(double x) {
    double result = 1e-10;
    for (auto n = -30; result < x; ++n)
      result = "\x1\x2\x5"[(30 + n) % 3] * pow(10, (30 + n) / 3 - 10);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сформировать множитель к текущему числу.

Известно, что:   `log10(1) = 0, log10(2) = 0.3, log10(5) = 0,7`.
При умножении этих чисел на положительную или отрицательную степень `10` дробная часть логарифма будет та же самая.

Умножая её на `4` и округляя по недостатку, получим индекс `0, 1, 2`.
Для индексов `0` и `2` множитель `4/2`, для индекса `1` - множитель `5/2`.

Программа (PHP):

```
function next_nice(&$n){
    $db = log10($n);                    // логарифм
    $frac = $db - floor($db);           // дробная часть
    $ind = (int)floor(4*$frac);         // индекс
    $n = $n * (5 - abs($ind-1)) / 2 ;   // умножение
    printf ("<br>next = %.9f", $n);
    return $n;
}

$n = 0.000000001;
while(next_nice($n) < 1E9);
```

Результаты:

```
next = 0.000000002
next = 0.000000005
next = 0.000000010
next = 0.000000020
next = 0.000000050
next = 0.000000100
next = 0.000000200
next = 0.000000500
next = 0.000001000
next = 0.000002000
next = 0.000005000
next = 0.000010000
next = 0.000020000
next = 0.000050000
next = 0.000100000
next = 0.000200000
next = 0.000500000
next = 0.001000000
next = 0.002000000
next = 0.005000000
next = 0.010000000
next = 0.020000000
next = 0.050000000
next = 0.100000000
next = 0.200000000
next = 0.500000000
next = 1.000000000
next = 2.000000000
next = 5.000000000
next = 10.000000000
next = 20.000000000
next = 50.000000000
next = 100.000000000
next = 200.000000000
next = 500.000000000
next = 1000.000000000
next = 2000.000000000
next = 5000.000000000
next = 10000.000000000
next = 20000.000000000
next = 50000.000000000
next = 100000.000000000
next = 200000.000000000
next = 500000.000000000
next = 1000000.000000000
next = 2000000.000000000
next = 5000000.000000000
next = 10000000.000000000
next = 20000000.000000000
next = 50000000.000000000
next = 100000000.000000000
next = 200000000.000000000
next = 500000000.000000000
next = 1000000000.000000000
```