# Как нарисовать гистограмму

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, статистика

Есть произвольный набор чисел, надо нарисовать его [гистограмму](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0) - график количества попаданий этих чисел в некоторые интервалы (ведерки).

Исходный набор числел имеет некоторые границы (например это 95-й процентиль нормального распределения), т.е. область значений - это **не** `(-inf, +inf)`.
Можно использовать "ведерки" одного размера.
Для подбора оптимального размера ведерка можно использовать числовой ряд [`1, 2, 5`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487796/177684).

Если решение использует псевдографику - то надо учитывать что окно консоли имеет фиксированные размеры, например 80*25.

Производительность кода совершенно не важна. Главное - это простота и лаконичность.

**Пример:**

Для исходных данных, сгенерированных следующим С++ кодом

```
mt19937 prng;
vector<double> data;
for (auto i = 0; i != 500; ++i) data.push_back(normal_distribution<double>(0, 5)(prng));
for (auto i = 0; i != 500; ++i) data.push_back(normal_distribution<double>(30, 5)(prng));
```

Можно нарисовать такую гистограмму:

```
 -10 |= 9
  -5 |============ 65
   0 |==================================================================== 348
   5 |============= 69
  10 |= 8
  15 |== 12
  20 |============= 67
  25 |================================= 170
  30 |=================================== 182
  35 |=========== 57
  40 |== 12
  45 | 1
```

Пример сигнатуры функции (C++):

```
void histogram(vector<double> data, int rows = 25, int cols = 80, ostream& out = cout);
```

Comment: А интервал и размер bucket'а известны заранее?

Answer (score 1):

**C#**

```
static void histogram(List<double> data, TextWriter @out, int rows = 2, int cols = 80)
{
    double min = data.Min(), max = data.Max(), bucketSize = (max - min) / (rows - 1);
    // сгруппируем в ведёрки, Key = номер ведёрка
    var buckets = data.GroupBy(d => Math.Floor((d - min) / bucketSize)).OrderBy(g => g.Key);
    // и вывод
    foreach (var g in buckets.OrderBy(g => g.Key)) // отсортируем по ведёрку 
        @out.WriteLine("{0,6} |{1} {2}", (g.Key * bucketSize + min).ToString("0.00"),
                       new string('=', (cols - 20) * g.Count() / data.Count), g.Count());
}
```

При таких данных:

```
var r = new Random();
var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(_ => r.NextDouble() * 100).
             Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(_ => r.NextDouble() * 20)).ToList();
histogram(data, Console.Out, rows: 15);
```

выдаёт результат:

```
  0,01 |============ 431
  7,13 |============ 410
 14,25 |========== 354
 21,36 |== 69
 28,48 |== 76
 35,60 |= 65
 42,71 |== 72
 49,83 |== 73
 56,95 |== 77
 64,06 |== 85
 71,18 |= 62
 78,30 |== 82
 85,41 |== 68
 92,53 |== 75
 99,65 | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### С++, с использованием `std::map`

```
template<typename FwdIter>
void histogram(FwdIter first, FwdIter last, int rows = 25, int cols = 80, std::ostream& out = std::cout) {
    // Выбор оптимального размера ведерка.
    auto minmax = std::minmax_element(first, last);
    auto bucket_width = 1e-10;  // http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487842/177684
    for (auto n = -30; bucket_width < (*minmax.second - *minmax.first) / rows; ++n)
        bucket_width = "\x1\x2\x5"[(30 + n) % 3] * pow(10, (30 + n) / 3 - 10);

    std::map<int, int> buckets;  // Индекс - номер ведерка.
    std::for_each(first, last, [&](auto x) { ++buckets[int(x / bucket_width)]; });

    int max_n = std::max_element(begin(buckets), end(buckets), [](auto& a, auto& b) { return a.second < b.second; })->second;
    double n_scale = std::min(1.0, double(cols - 12) / max_n);
    // Мы должны перебрать все ведерки, даже если их нет в buckets.
    for (int i = buckets.begin()->first; i <= buckets.rbegin()->first; ++i) {
        out << std::setw(4) << i * bucket_width << " |";
        std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char>(out), int(buckets[i] * n_scale), '=');
        out << ' ' << buckets[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Результат - как на гистограмме в вопросе.