# проверка младшей цифры на кратность заданному числу

Tags: c++

Есть задача,подсчитать количество натуральных чисел в диапазоне [a,b), в которых младшая цифра кратная заданной. Застрял на том как выделить младшую цифру. Большое спасибо!

```
#include <iostream>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int k;
    int c;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "input chislo";
    cin >> k;
    cout << "a=";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b=";
    cin >> b;

    while (a < b)
    {
        while (a > 0)
        {
            c = a % 10;

            if (c % k == 0)
            {
                count += 1;
            }
        }

        a += 1;
    }

    cout << "kilkist = " << count << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вас интересует только как найти младшую цифру десятичной записи числа `n` - то это `n%10`.

**Update**
А теперь скажите, меняется ли значение `a` в теле цикла `while (a > 0)`?
Правда, вряд ли?
Так что `a` всегда больше нуля?
Так что цикл вечный?

Но вы еще вот о чем подумайте... Например, проверяем все числа от 0 до 999999999. Делится ли... ну, на 7. Получается только 0 и 7, так? Так стоит ли перебирать миллиард чисел, если проще умножить 100 миллионов на 2?

Так что, может, перепишете вашу программу?

Comment: ,я так и сделал, но у меня почему то, при компиляции, после ввода данных ничего не происходит

Comment: Ну я же намекнул - *"Если вас интересует только"*...

Comment: ,почему именно 100 млн?

Comment: Потому что именно столько десятков в миллиарде :)

Comment: ааа,осенило,спасибо!)

Comment: хотя, смотрите, перебирать надо, как тогда определить в диапазоне от  [24 до 35)

Comment: @Harry: Нужна ещё спецобработка для [отрицательных чисел](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229375/10105).

Comment: Ну правильно, нужно добраться до круглого десятка снизу, сверху, а дальше просто разность... Или добраться снизу до той же последней цифры, что и сверху... Или...

Comment: @VladD Поскольку нас интересует только нулевой результат - это неважно. Важнее то, что между отрицательными и положительными - если `a` и `b` с разным знаком - есть нуль, который надо учитывать особо.

Comment: Ну, я к тому, что `n % 10` — не младшая цифра, а младшая цифра плюс знак как бы.

Comment: Ну и отрицательные числа наверное надо рассматривать отдельно. Нижняя граница +3 при поиске цифр, делящихся на 2, означает 3 вхождения в текущей десятке, а для отрицательного случая — только 2 вхождения.