# Деление с остатком: можно ли избежать переполнения?

Tags: формулы, integer-overflow

Добрый день!

В решении своей задачи мне необходимо находить остаток от деления произведения чисел. Формально это можно записать так:

> x = (a * b) mod c, где a, b и с - целые положительные числа, и с > a.

Дело в том, что при реализации этого этапа задачи на языке программирования (пишу на C#) будет происходить переполнение целочисленного типа при значениях `>50 000` (`Int32`).

На языке C# это выражение у меня выглядит так:

```
x = (a * b) % c;
```

**Вопрос:** Существует ли формула, позволяющая разбить вышеописанную формулу на выражение с двумя mod'ами или существует ли способ, позволяющий как-то избежать вычисления произведения двух больших чисел? Благодарю.

Comment: Может использовать `Int64`

Comment: @diraria это как вариант, но вопрос не в этом. Я просто не хотел бы работать с `Int64`, поэтому хотел узнать, существует ли формула, упрощающая вычисление.

Comment: @diraria что-то вроде `(a + b) / c` = `a/c + b/c`

Comment: @diraria нет, это уж слишком для вычисления одной формулы) У меня в программе такая формула вычисляется около 50 000 раз:) а там еще помимо этого поиск в списке такого же размера.

Comment: Ну я всё равно напишу, почти дописал уже

Comment: @diraria хорошо, все же интересно взглянуть на это решение :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(a * b) mod c = ((a mod c) * (b mod c)) mod c
```

Comment: А если `a=50000`, `b=50000`, `c=10^9+7`?

Comment: Да, это то, что я хотел, благодарю! :) Но я тут подумал, что это мне не поможет избежать переполнения, если `a < c` и `b < c`. Но за формулу спасибо

Comment: Вопрос автора состоит в том, существует ли формула. Ответ дан.

Answer (score 4):

Прагматическое решение — используйте для умножения число большей разрядности, в вашем случае — `ulong`. Произведение двух положительных `int`'ов всегда помещается в `ulong`, поэтому при вычислении произведения переполнения не произойдёт. Однако, следите, чтобы ваши исходные числа были положительными.

Заметьте, что оператор `%` имеет смысл использовать только для положительных чисел, для отрицательных он [ведёт себя странно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229375/10105), поэтому для приведения числа к промежутку [0, c) вам придётся отдельно рассматривать знак числа.

Answer (score 3):

Ещё можно по аналогии с алгоритмом быстрого возведения в степень по модулю.

Работает за `O(log b)`, но зато корректно вычисляет для `a=50000`, `b=50000`, `c=10^9+7`:

- Пусть `b = 2k + r`, где `r` это `0` либо `1`.
- Тогда `a * b = a * (2k + r) = a * 2k + a * r = 2a * k + (a или 0)`
- Таким образом, мы свели задачу умножения двух чисел к задачам

  - умножение числа на два
  - умножение двух чисел (но второе число в этот раз меньше в два раза)
  - сложение двух чисел

Код на C++ ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZwkV98)):

```
int multiply(int a, int b, int mod) {
    if (b == 0) {
        // a * 0 = 0
        return 0;
    } else {
        // b = 2k + r
        int k = b / 2;
        int r = b % 2;

        // a * (2k + r) = 2a * k + a * r
        return (multiply(a * 2 % mod, k, mod) + a * r) % mod;
    }
}
```