# Как поделить двоичное натуральное на 10 фиксированным количеством сдвигов, сложений и вычитаний?

Tags: любой-язык

Умножение на 10 можно представить в виде

```
x * 10 = x * 8 + x * 2 = (x << 3) + (x << 1)
```

А можно ли каким-то подобным способом (сдвигами, сложениями и вычитаниями) делить на 10? (Вычитание 10 из `x` до посинения - не подходит.)

Comment: Можно. Я напишу, если никто не опередит.

Comment: @VladD Ой, нет, пишите лучше вы :) Я только намекну на то, что можно взять книгу Уоррена "Алгоритмыческие трюки для программистов" и найти там соответствующие методы...

Comment: @Harry, там одуреешь искать. Автор, если быстро и для дела нужно, то можно и поделиться прогаммулькой

Comment: @avp, ну как для дела, [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787954/ребус-volvo-fiat-motor) полным перебором решал, там деление на 10. Компилятор его, скорее всего, и так оптимизирует на умножение и сдвиг. Вот, показалось интересным, можно ли обойтись без умножения.

Comment: Можно. Имеет смысл, если в вашем микропроцессоре нет аппаратуры умножения нужной разрядности. Сейчас кину код в ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Деление беззнаковых целых 32 и 64 разрядных на 10 с возвратом частного и получением остатка.

```
// http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf
uint32_t divu10(uint32_t n, uint32_t *rem) {
  uint32_t q, r;
  q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
  q = q + (q >> 4);
  q = q + (q >> 8);
  q = q + (q >> 16);
  q = q >> 3;
  //  orig: r = n - q*10;
  r = n - ((q << 3) + (q << 1));
  *rem = r > 9 ? r - 10 : r;

  //  orig: return q + ((r + 6) >> 4);
  return q + (r > 9);
}


uint64_t divu64_10(uint64_t n, uint32_t *rem) {
  uint64_t q, r;
  q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
  q = q + (q >> 4);
  q = q + (q >> 8);
  q = q + (q >> 16);
  q = q + (q >> 32);
  q = q >> 3;
  //  orig: r = n - q*10;
  r = n - ((q << 3) + (q << 1));
  *rem = r > 9 ? r - 10 : r;

  //  orig: return q + ((r + 6) >> 4);
  return q + (r > 9);
}
```

Практически используется для вывода `uint64_t` на 32-bit микропроцессоре, в котором нет 64-разрядного умножения.

Answer (score 6):

Давайте посмотрим, как оптимизируют деление на 10 популярные компиляторы. Например, для вот такой функции:

```
int divide10(int32_t num)
{
    return num / 10;
}
```

MSVC [производит такой код](https://godbolt.org/g/oDkEk7):

```
mov      eax, 1717986919      ; 66666667H
imul     ecx
sar      edx, 2

mov      eax, edx
shr      eax, 31
add      eax, edx
```

Переведём его на нормальный язык.

Первые 3 строчки означают умножение числа на 0x66666667 = (2^34 + 6)/10 (тут ^ означает степень). Старшие 32 бита результата (edx) мы затем сдвигаем ещё на 2 бита вправо, итого выходит `(x * 0x66666667) >> 34`.

Команда `shr eax, 31` — сдвиг на 31 бит, получает знаковый бит результата. Он прибавляется к самому результату. То есть, для отрицательных чисел прибавляется 1. Итого

```
int r = (int)((x * 0x66666667L) >> 34);
r += (r < 0);
```

GCC, Clang и Intel Compiler производят аналогичный код, только они делают знаковое расширение вместо беззнакового.

---

Разбор математического обоснования такой замены проводится [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16218823/276994). Вот краткая выжимка:

Для делимого `n >= 0` можно представить `n` в виде `10 * q + r`, где `q` — искомый результат, а `r` — остаток. Получаем

```
(x * 0x66666667L) >> 34 == [(10 * q + r) * (0x66666667L) / 2^34]
```

(`^` означает возведение в степень, `[]` — целую часть от деления). Наш числитель:

```
(2^34 + 6)/10 * (10 * q + r) = q * 2^34 + 6 * q + 0x66666667L * r
```

При делении на `2^34` первое слагаемое делится нацело и даёт искомое `q`, так что нужно убедиться, что остальное даёт 0. Это так, поскольку `q < [2^31/10]`, а `r <= 9`, так что

```
6 * q + 0x66666667L * r < 6 * 214748364 + 0x66666667L * 9 == 15676630635 < 2^34
```

Для отрицательных `n` аналогично доказывается, что «хвост» нашего выражения даёт нулевой вклад, но т. к. при делении отрицательных чисел процессор должен делать округление [в сторону нуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229375/10105), приходится добавлять компенсирующую единицу.

---

Как именно получать такое представление, лучше справится в книжках. Но мораль этого такова: подобные мелкие оптимизации компиляторы делают куда лучше нас. Поэтому не нужно пытаться «помочь» компилятору, он, поверьте, делает это (мелкие оптимизации кода) куда лучше нас с вами.

Эпоха ручных оптимизаций прошла. Оптимизируйте алгоритмы.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Matt Godbolt: Что мой компилятор сделал для меня?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/339962/)

Comment: Тьфу, не заметил, что в вопросе без _умножений_.

Comment: Оставлю, может, кому-то пригодится.

Comment: если честно, я просто скопировал вопрос с enSO, чтобы такой же был на ruSO. Оба ответа лучше, чем ответы там.

Answer (score 1):

Общий смысл в том, что надо умножить число на 0.0(9). Физически бесконечное число девяток нереализуемо. Поэтому наиболее точный коэффициент, обеспечивающий такое умножение будет иметь значение 1717986919/(2^32) в алгоритме от VladD и 858993459/(2^31) в алгоритме от avp.
Алгоритм от avp в процессе работы оперирует с данными, не превышающими разрядность исходного числа.
Алгоритм от VladD требует удвоенной размерности промежуточных вычислений.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос