# Как проверить попадание времени из расписания между двумя датами?

Tags: алгоритм, время, любой-язык

Есть некое расписание, в котором, например, указано, что что-то должно происходить каждый день в 11:47. И есть две даты - последнее успешное выполнение действия, к примеру 04/07 11:51 и текущий момент времени - 05/07 11:48.

Как максимально просто и правильно написать проверку попадания времени из расписания между двумя датами?

С учетом того, что последнее выполнение могло быть несколько дней назад - тогда проверка должна вернуть True. Или, к примеру, время 23:00 должно корректно вернуть True при попадании между двумя датами 22:00 и 01:00.

Примеры:

```
"01:00", "01/07/00:00", "01/07/02:00" - True
"11:00", "01/07/12:00", "05/07/12:00" - True
"01:00", "04/07 03:00", "05/07 02:00" - True
"01:00", "05/07 01:30", "05/07 02:00" - False
"12:00", "04/07 13:00", "05/07 11:00" - False
```

---

Свой **неверный, но дорабатываемый вариант** на Delphi:

```
function CheckTime(aTime, aFrom, aTo: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  d1, d2: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := False;

  // Если прошло больше суток, то попадание точно есть
  // Проверка необходима, если к примеру на входе "11:00", "01/07/12:00", "05/07/12:00"
  if aTo - aFrom > 1 then
    Exit(True);

  // В рамках одной даты проверяем простое попадание в интервал
  if DateOf(aFrom) = DateOf(aTo) then
    if (aTime > TimeOf(aFrom)) and (aTime <= TimeOf(aTo)) then
      Exit(True);

  // С разными датами самый сложный случай, и в нем возможны еще ошбки ..
  d1 := DateOf(aFrom) + aTime;
  d2 := DateOf(aTo) + aTime;
  if (d1 > aFrom) or (d2 <= aTo) then
    Exit(True);
end;
```

Comment: Давайте разные даты времени и смотрите, куда оно попадает?...

Comment: @Harry "разные даты времени и куда оно попадает" - не понимаю что вы имеете ввиду. Уточните плиз?

Comment: Посмотреть 04/07 11:47 - после него уже было; но 05/07 11:47 - вроде как нет - что-то в таком духе. Тут я сам точно сформулировать не могу, потому и ограничиваюсь комментарием...

Answer (score 1):

Расчеты необходимо вести "по модулю" суток. Я буду писать на C#, поэтому пользуюсь средствами, предоставляемыми им и буду переводить всё в тики. Вы можете расчет вести, например, в секундах, это не повлияет, но может быть удобнее на используемой платформе.

В расчеты по модулю не вписывается картина, когда между начальной и конечной датами прошло более суток, поэтому это мы рассмотрим отдельно.

Для того, чтобы не учитывать варианты, когда конечная дата по модулю меньше начальной, мы примем за начало отсчета начальную дату и вычисления по модулю будем производить относительно нее.

Теперь всё становится просто:

```
static bool IsBetween(TimeSpan time, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    // Если прошло более суток, то сразу возвращаем true
    if ((endDate - startDate).TotalDays >= 1) return true;
    // Начало отсчета
    var reference = startDate.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerDay;
    // Конечное время по модулю суток относительно начальной даты
    var endRef = (endDate.Ticks - reference) % TimeSpan.TicksPerDay;
    // Входное время по модулю суток относительно начальной даты
    // Из-за проблемы с остатком от деления отрицательного числа
    //  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229375/218063
    // Приходится прибавлять модуль сравнения, это законно, см.
    //  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сравнение_по_модулю
    var pointRef = (time.Ticks + TimeSpan.TicksPerDay - reference) % TimeSpan.TicksPerDay;
    return endRef >= pointRef && pointRef > 0;
}
```

Проверка:

```
Console.WriteLine(IsBetween(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 07, 04, 03, 00, 00), new DateTime(2018, 07, 05, 02, 00, 00))); // True
Console.WriteLine(IsBetween(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 07, 05, 01, 00, 00), new DateTime(2018, 07, 05, 02, 00, 00))); // False
Console.WriteLine(IsBetween(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0), new DateTime(2018, 07, 05, 01, 30, 00), new DateTime(2018, 07, 05, 02, 00, 00))); // False
```