# Как интерполировать значения в геометрических градусах?

Tags: любой-язык, геометрия

Мне нужно интерполировать угол поворота некоторого объекта между двумя значениями задаваемыми в геометрических градусах (от 0 до 359). Однако простая интерполяция не подходит, т.к. при попытке интерполировать между 10 и 350, объект будет делать поворот по большой дуге (340 градусов по часовой стрелке), вместо того чтобы повернуть на -20 градусов против часовой стрелки. То есть мне надо как-то выбрать меньшую дугу и интерполировать поворот объекста по ней.

Вопрос, как правильно интерполировать значения между двумя углами?

---

*Если кто знает, как правильнее сформулировать задачу, то поправьте плиз*

Comment: Ничего не понял. У вас заданы 2 точки на окружности (2 угла) и вам надо определить направление поворота, с минимальным углом?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да. Я не знаю как точнее сформулировать задачу в более общем виде точнее (что-то про модульную арифметику вроде)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилась вот такая функция:

```
function LerpDirection(aDir1, aDir2, aFrac: Single): Single;
begin
  // Углы могут быть от 0 до 359
  if Abs(aDir1 - aDir2) <= 180 then
    // Просто интерполируем
    Result := Lerp(aDir1, aDir2, aFrac)
  else
  begin
    // Интерполируем по дуге через 0
    if aDir1 > aDir2 then
      Result := Lerp(aDir1 - 360, aDir2, aFrac)
    else
      Result := Lerp(aDir1, aDir2 - 360, aFrac);

    if Result < 0 then
      Result := Result + 360;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, более читабельнее получается, если писать так:

```
// Правильнее заменить на остаток, но есть проблема, описанная
//  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229375/218063
static double AngleNorm(double a) => a < 0 ? a + 360 : a;

static double AngleLerp(double a1, double a2, double c)
{
    var ad = AngleNorm(a2 - a1); // Угол при прямом движении
    var md = ad > 180 ? -1 : 1; // Направление движения
    var an = ad > 180 ? 360 - ad : ad; // Кратчайший угол
    // или даже: var an = AngleNorm(md * ad);
    return AngleNorm(a1 + md * an * c); // Движемся от a1
}
```

<sub>[Решение на Pascal](http://tpcg.io/6ZXj8t)</sub>

Comment: Так явно короче, но логика более запутанная получается.

Comment: Ну я наоборот в вашем решении запутался. Здесь всё прямолинейно: определяем в какую сторону двигаться (вперед или назад), определяем минимальный угол, движемся из начальной точки в нужную сторону на нужный угол (an * c). Но вам, конечно, виднее, какой вариант выбрать :)

Comment: Вот и хорошо, пусть будет 2 варианта, кому какой удобнее! )