# Найти остаток от деления

Tags: алгоритм, математика, криптография

Прошу,помогите!
Есть такое задание :

> Найти остаток от деления числа 59 · 60 · 61 − 62 (mod 7)

Я сделал следующее :

1.Использовал теорему (a1 + a2) (mod b) = (r1 + r2)(mod b)

Правда,действия заменил - (a1 * a2 * a3 - a4)(mod b) = (r1 * r2 * r3 - r4)(mod b)
Так же можно было сделать?)

Выражение перешло к такому виду :

> (59 * 60 * 61 - 62) (mod 7) = r1 * r2 * r3 - r4 (mod 7);

2.Нахожу r по формуле :

> rn = an(mod b)

```
r1 = a1 (mod 7) = 59 (mod 7) = 3;
r2 = 60 (mod 7) = 4;
r3 = 61 (mod 7) = 5
r4 = ???
```

С r4 у меня проблемы,ибо я пытаюсь найти остаток от a4 =-62.

И в итоге у меня получается остаток 1.(-62 mod 7) = 1

А в книге a4 берется как просто 62 без минуса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в ней получается 62 (mod 7) = 6

Вопрос :

> Почему берется a4 как "62" , а не "-62"?

Comment: Мне кажется с этими вопросами Вам надо не сюда, по данному вопросу можно слишком долго вести дискуссии. Слишком много но в данном вопросе.

Comment: >> 62 (mod 7) = 6<< — осчитался `3*4*5+1 == 61` по модулю 7 соответственно 5 получается...

Comment: @ Kel Fish Хм,посмотрите на разделы,которые я указал.Это как-то связано с html-программированием?

Comment: @Fat-Zer да я понимаю,что если взять 62 (mod 7) = 6 и ответ будет 5.Но почему мы берем 62,а не "-62"?И не считаем остаток вот так : -62 (mod 7)?

Comment: @Sckoriy нет, не связано, а в чем дело?

Comment: @Kel Fish , я забыл в чем)

Comment: Не понимаю, в чём проблема. Почему -62 % 7 равен 1? Почитайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229375/Остаток-для-негативного-аргумента-ошибочен) про модуль негативного аргумента

Comment: @cppquestions , потому что я использую условие "модуль" >= 0.Я понимаю,что можно использовать отрицательный модуль.Но в данном случаем мне нужен только >= 0.И в итоге получиться 1.

Comment: Из вики: "то есть остаток от деления должен быть неотрицательным числом и по абсолютной величине меньше делителя". При делении по модулю отрицательного числа, множитель стает отрицательным, а не остаток -62 % 7   ==>  (-8*7 +5 )%7 Пять уходит в остаток, а -8*7 аннигилируется

Comment: @Serhii Dikobrazko , странно,что у вас получилось так.Как у вас может быть остаток 5,если вы в итоге должны получиться число -62 по формуле    a = qb + r, q - частное , r - остаток.У вас не правильно посчитан остаток.(-8*7 - 6)

Comment: @Sckoriy все просто. Я не перепроверял) И не такое получится)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И в твоих рассуждениях и в примере одинаковые преобразования, просто по-разному знак выносится за скобки.

У тебя:

```
(a - b) mod p == (a + (-b)) mod p == ((a mod p) + ((-b) mod p)) mod p
```

В букваре:

```
(a - b) mod p == ((a mod p) - (b mod p)) mod p
```

В итоге ответ всё равно один.