# Как из проекции единичного вектора на оси x и y получить направление в градусах 0..360?

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, инспекция-кода, векторы

Дано направление вектора в таком формате:

1. Направление ветра: проекция единичного вектора на ось X
2. Направление ветра: проекция единичного вектора на ось Y

Как мне получить направление в градусах?

Получается что направление ветра это вектор (x, y) и необходимо найти угол между системой координат, т.е. вектором (0, 0)?

```
def __projection2angle(self, x,y):   
        delta_x = x - 0
        delta_y = y - 0
        rad = math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x)     
        deg =  rad * (180 / math.pi)
        if deg<=0:
            deg+=360
        elif deg>=360:
            deg-=360
        return deg
```

Что то я сомневаюсь.

Comment: Нормализовать лучше делением по модулю: `deg = (deg + 360) % 360`

Comment: @vp_arth, чем лучше?

Comment: _`deg>=360`_ - ни когда не выполнится. Остальное вроде верно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, симпатичнее. Вкусовщина, конечно-же

Comment: atan2 вернёт значение от (-pi, pi). Поэтому, если к rad прибавить pi, он будет в (0, 2*pi), а после `deg =  rad * (180 / math.pi)` в `deg` будет значение из (0, 360)

Comment: @ⷶⷩⷮⷪⷩ, если прибавить пи (а не 2*пи), то получится неверный угол.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В целом вроде верно, но я бы сократил:

```
def angle(self, x, y):   
  deg = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
  return deg if deg >= 0 else deg + 360
```

или ещё более красивый вариант:

```
def angle(x, y):
  deg = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
  return deg % 360
```

Код полностью: https://ideone.com/c9MQJa и https://ideone.com/sGXhgr

```
import math

def angle(x, y):
  deg = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
  return deg if deg >= 0 else deg + 360

print(angle( 1,  0)) #   0
print(angle( 1,  1)) #  45
print(angle( 0,  1)) #  90
print(angle(-1,  1)) # 135
print(angle(-1,  0)) # 180
print(angle(-1, -1)) # 225
print(angle( 0, -1)) # 270
print(angle( 1, -1)) # 315
```

Comment: Можно переписать `return deg if deg >= 0 else deg + 360` в `return deg % 360`: https://ideone.com/sGXhgr В python это работает, см. дополнительно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229375/Остаток-для-негативного-аргумента-ошибочен#comment229514_229503

Comment: @АндрейNOP, дополнил.

Answer (score 2):

Найти угол между двумя векторами можно через `dot product`:

`fi = arccos(dot(vec1,vec2));`

тот же вариант :

`fi = arccos(vec1*vec2/|vec1|*|vec2|)`,

где `|val|` это длина вектора.

То есть, если у вас есть вектора `A` и нужно найти угол между ним и осью `x`, тогда:

`fi = arccos(dot(A,x));`

Comment: Чем atan2 не угодил? Про арккосинус не верю - он не весь круг возвращает.

Comment: Верное замечание. Область значений арккосинуса [0, pi], т.е. половина круга, в то время как у atan2 (-pi, pi)

Comment: @raviga, мой вариант - как в вопросе автора.

Comment: Впрочем, посмотрел повнимательнее и запостил. Вроде бы должно работать? UPDATE: Сам проверил - работает :)