# Чем отличается a // 2 и int(a / 2) в python?

Tags: python

Чем отличается a // 2 и int(a / 2) в python?

Я писал программу и попробовал 2 метода:

1. a // 2 - всё работает хорошо.
2. int(a / 2) - почему то возвращает не правильный ответ.

Кто нибудь знает чем эти функции вообще отличаются?

Comment: Если `a` это float, то `a//2` вернёт тип float, а `int(a/2)` вернёт тип int

Comment: Кроме того, если `a` является отрицательным числом, то результат будет различаться

Comment: Приведите примеры - что там неправильно работает?

Answer (score 2):

### Пример

Разница, если `a` < 0 и `a` не кратно 2. Например,

```
int(-3/2) # -1
-3//2 # -2
```

### Почему?

#### Первый случай `int`

`-3/2` - это `-1.5`, переводим в int - `-1`.

#### Второй случай `//`

`//` - это целая часть от деления с остатком. Что такое деление с остатком? Поделим a на b:
`a = bk + q`, где `q` - это остаток: `0 <= q < b`
Теперь поделим `-3` на `2`:
`-3 = 2*(-2)+1`. Следовательно ответ `-2`.

Comment: это правильный ответ как ни странно (я до сих пор не могу принять, что целая часть от деления -3 на 2 - это -2, а не -1). в си-подобных языках -3/2 == -1.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов с делением с остатком и "вспомним математику" - не все так очевидно, тут есть хороший [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229375/%d0%9e%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd) на эту тему

Answer (score 1):

Если переменная `a` у вас относится к типу `int`(целое число) , то никакой разницы не будет, в обоих случаях переменная будет относится к типу `int`. Если переменная `a` относится к типу `float`(число с плавающей точкой) , то в случае `a//2` оно будет возвращать тип `float` , а во втором случае вы сами выражению `int(a/2)` присваиваете тип `int`

Comment: В питоне есть такое понятие как "тип функции"?

Comment: @yolosora Нету , прошу прощения за опечатку , неправильно выразил мысль