# Остаток от деления в Java и Python

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, java-8, mod

Решаю одну и ту же простую задачу на Python и Java. Алгоритм идентичен, но результаты почему-то разные. Причина нашлась: в решении использую "%" (остаток от деления) и, если первая переменная имеет отрицательное значение, то почему-то результаты разнятся:

```
print(-1 % 109) #Python.
```

Вывод: 108

```
System.out.println(-1 % 109); //Java.
```

Вывод: -1

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему разные результаты?

Comment: Разная реализация нахождения остатка для отрицательных аргументов зависит от конкретного языка. Оба результата правильны. Какой результат вам нужен?

Comment: В [вике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC) есть статья, рассматривающая эту тему (в ней есть таблица про знак остатка в разных языках)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Мне нужен был именно положительный остаток, как в Python. Решение найдено с использованием Math.floorMod()

Answer (score 5):

Проблема решена.
Натолкнул на решение этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/229503/432090. Остаток от деления может быть двух типов:

> - Remainder - остаток от деления (может быть и отрицательным)
> - Residual - буквально осадок (всегда положительный)

В Java "%" - это Remainder, в Python - Residual.

А вот так можно получить именно положительный остаток на Java (в смысле Residual, он мне был нужен по условию задачи):

```
System.out.println(Math.floorMod(-1, 109));
```

Вывод: 108